# How do i control static directory resources

Tags: django, static, collectstatic

```
<script src="./home/static/js/2.d754fc32.chunk.js"></script>
```

Currently my html file points to this. What static variable django setting.py do I declare to make the HTML point to

```
<script src="./home/static/static/js/2.d754fc32.chunk.js"></script>
```

currently in setting.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../frontend/build')
]

STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/web/home/static/'
STATIC_URL = 'home/static/'
```

My build folder contains a static file inside as well.

Comment: what do you mean by What static variable django setting.py do I declare to make the HTML point to, please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

if STATICFILES_DIR is in the right place:

You just have to `{% load 'static' %}` on the top of your html (after extend), and to set the css file:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/style.css' %}">
```

if you want a img from there would be:

```
<img src="{% static '<PathOfImage>/img.png' %}">
```